# How to fix "Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile"

Tags: ruby

I have tried multiple times to uninstall bundler and reinstall bundler, and somehow, I keep seeing this error:

```
➜  gem uninstall bundler
Remove executables:
  bundler

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  y
Removing bundler
Successfully uninstalled bundler-2.0.1

➜  gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-2.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
1 gem installed

➜  bundle
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.16.6) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
```

Comment: Have you tried `gem install bundler -v 1.17.3`

Comment: Silly solution, but I just put `BUNDLED WITH 2.0.1` in my gemfile.lock and now I don't get any more errors.

Comment: I was wondering how to fix it, in my case if someone wants to reproduce the error pattern ... Let's say that I have updated my rails project to the newest version and just before I have updated the ruby version too of the rails app project. And at this moment I had a message that invited me to install new bundler and I did it. Then I decided for some reasons to downgrade to the previous ruby version. Once the downgrade have been done I had the same warning message. I have finally fixed the issue  by rm the gem lock and build it again...

Comment: I've got the same problem. My project says it created the Gemfile.lock with version 1.17.3 but is running 1.17.2. Well, if 1.17.2 ist running then how did the Gemfile.lock get to be created with 1.17.3? It's very mystifying. 1.17.3 is obviously installed on my machine and was running when the lockfile was created (just a few days ago), and now the version has changed? And why has it changed to an older version of bundler *especially* when I have been *up*grading ruby, Gems and Rails? I'll try the method used by @v2lrf, but I'd still like to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and install again the required version in the warning, in your case it is requiring version 1.17.3

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
```